# Problem parsar a date with Carbon and get differences PHP , Carbon

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I have a List of records in my database and I am presenting problems using php carbon

First, I try to perform the cast of a date, in my database I have `2019-11-13 22:55:00` and when I do the cast `Carbon::parse($fieldDateTime)->format('d m Y H: m: s')` I get as a result `13 11 2019 21:11:00`, Why is this happening ?

I have a list of records and I want to filter them so they have an approximate date of 3 hours, to alert the user that in 3 hours he has to do an action.

```
    $filtered = $collection->filter(function($cita){
        $diffMinutes = Carbon::parse($fieldDateTime)->diffInMinutes(Carbon::now()->subMinutes(180));
        return  Carbon::parse($fieldDateTime)->isToday() &&  
            ($diffMinutes==0)  ;
    });
```

How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get your date value from the database and convert it into the carbon instance. Then, you can get the subtraction function from carbon.

```
$time = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($YourTimeFromDataBase);
$minutes = Carbon::now()->diffInMinutes($time);
 //it will give you in minute. then you can easily check if the time exceed 3*60 mins ort not.
if($minutes>180){
//do somthing
}else{
//do something   
}
```